# Store data from TableView in the NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

if got a tableview and the user can add strings into it:

```
-(IBAction)textFieldDidEndEditing {

NSString *string = textField.text;
[tableArray addObject:string];
[mainTableView reloadData];
textField.text = @"";
```

}

how can I store the content of the tableView into the NSUserdefaults?
can anybody give me a short example please?

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try storing whole Array as an Object into NSUserDefaults

```
NSUserDefaults *default = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[default setObject:tableArray forKey:@"key"];
```

& now to fetch it from NSUserDefautls:

```
NSArray *array = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"key"];
```

Hope this solve some sort of problem of urs. :)

Comment: try NSArray *array=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key"];

Comment: > Try just to print --NSLog(%@,[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"key"]);

Comment: Simply try to print value instead of taking it in Array. NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"key"]);